# Call a method in a .cs from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, forms

I'm stacking with the following problem: I want to create a Template witch contains forms (3 textboxes and a button).Inside this template, through a javascript, have to call a function (CRUD method) that is inside a .cs.

So...that's one of my CRUD function in EmployeeBL.cs :

```
[WebMethod]

public static bool CreateEmployee(int Id, string Nome, string Cognome) 
{ ...}
```

while here it's my Employee.tpl witch should call CreateEmployee():

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 400px">

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="Form"
          data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
          data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
          data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
          data-bv-submitbuttons='button[type="submit"]'>
        <div class="form-group">
        {Message}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id" placeholder="User name" value="{Model.Id}"
                data-bv-notempty-message ="{UserNameNotEmptyMessage}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" value="{Model.FirstName}"
                data-bv-notempty-message="{FirstNameNotEmptyMessage}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="{Model.LastName}" />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" id="myButton" >Create Employee</button>
    </div>
```

Now always inside this tpl put a script like here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$("#Form").bootstrapValidator();

    $("#myButton").click(function(){

  var Id=foo($('#Id').val());
  var FirstName= foo($('#FirstName').val());
  var LastName=foo($('#LastName').val());



 });
```

});

Summarizing: i need to create an Employee (with Id,LastName,FirstName) that goes to write on my DB via clicking on Button 
So my question is how to set visible the namespace of EmployeeBL.cs and how to call it's method CreateEmployee() inside script (clicking on Button)? Thx in advance!!

Comment: You can't just invoke code on the server from the browser, you need to use AJAX to invoke that `WebMethod`.  There are a number of examples available on a Google search for "ASP.NET webmethod AJAX" or something similar.  I haven't used web methods so I'm not sure which example is better than others.

Comment: @David I wouldn't say that merits the phrase "you can't" - it's just important to understand what the two computers are doing when you make that call, and don't expect constant communication.

Comment: @Katana314: "Can't" seems pretty applicable here.  JavaScript code running on one machine can't call a method in C# running on another machine.  It *can*, however, make an HTTP request to some endpoint on that machine which itself invokes that method.  But JavaScript in the browser legitimately "can't" reference C# on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
function createUser()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPageName.aspx/CreateEmployee",
        data: {Id: foo($('#Id').val()), Nome: foo($('#FirstName').val()),Cognome:foo($('#LastName').val()) },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
             alert('Ok');            }
        error: function (request, status, thrownError) {
           alert(thrownError);
   }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will work, but I'm not sure what is foo() function does? You might want to try without it.

Answer (score 1):

@Yuri: First of all Ty so much for help.Same time i found out that is better avoid this way. It was my fault cause i skipped telling you i'm working with ACSPNET with Owin and MVC pattern. So i created MVC files and a Business Logic one..In Controller under the function Invoke() i have to find a method to call EmployeeBL.CreateEmployee() and same time return a template like here:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller<EmployeeModel>
{
    public override ControllerResponse Invoke()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>{

           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,Model.Id.ToString()),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,Model.Name),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,Model.Surname)

       };

        return newTpl(GetView<EmployeeView().Get(Model,Html.MessageBox.Show(StringTable.EmployeeModel)) , StringTable.PageTitleCreateEmployee);
    }
}
```

where Get() function is defined in this way:

```
public class EmployeeView : View 
{
    public ITemplate Get(EmployeeModel viewModel = null, string message = null)
    {
        return
            TemplateFactory.Load("Employee.tpl")
                            .Model(viewModel)
                            .Set().Set("Message", message);
    }
}
```

Thus in Employee.tpl is defined only forms and button.

Comment: PS. Yes i forgot to clear [WebMethod] above CreateEmployee(). It was exactly my own experiment i did before using ajax